# array required, but Movie2 found

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
/**
   * Write a description of class Movie2 here.
     * 
       * @author (Austin J) 
         * @version (4/9/2016)
           */
public class Movie2
{
 public String title, studio;
 public int year;

 public Movie2 (String title, int year, String studio)
 {
     this.title = title;
     this.year = year;
     this.studio = studio;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        System.out.println(title + ", " + year + ", " + studio);
        return"";
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public String getStudio()
    {
        return studio;
    }

    public void sortTitles(Movie2 myMovies, int choice)
    {
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Movie2 myMovieTemp = myMovies[i];
            int insertIndex = 0;
            int k = i;

            while ( k > 0 && insertIndex == 0)
            {
                if (myMovies[i].getTitle().compareTo(myMovies[i - 1].getTitle() > (myMovies[i - 1].getTitel())))
                {
                    insertIndex = k;
                }
                else
                {
                    myMovies[k] = myMovies[k - 1];
                }
                k--;
            }

            myMovies[insertIndex] = next;
        }
    }

    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Movie2 myMoviesTemp = myMovies[i];
            int insertIndex = 0;
            int k = i;
            while ( k > 0 && insertIndex == 0)
            {
                if (myMoviesTemp.getTitle().compareTo(myMovies[k - 1].getTitle()) < 0)
                {
                    insertIndex = k;
                }
                else
                {
                    myMovies[k] = myMovies [k - 1];
                }
                myMovies[insertIndex] = myMoviesTemp;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid parameter");
    }
    return myMovies;
} 
}
```

The error occurs at line 45.

> "array required, but Movie2 found".

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell the question so we could understand what the program does without actually reading the whole program?

Answer (score 0):

Line 45:

```
Movie2 myMovieTemp = myMovies[i];
```

The variable `myMovies` is type `Movie2`. So what do you expect to happen when you try to reference index `[i]` of a `Movie2` object?

Perhaps you intended the `myMovies` property of the `sortTitles` method to be an array?

Answer (score 0):

`myMovies` is not an array, it is a variable of type `Movie2`. You are trying to access it as if it was an array.
It seems like you wanted to have an array of `Movie2` passed to your `sortTitles` function. So to use it as an array use `[]` in the method signature:

```
public void sortTitles(Movie2[] myMovies, int choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to change this line

```
public void sortTitles(Movie2 myMovies, int choice)
```

**into**

```
public void sortTitles(Movie2[] myMovies, int choice)
```

OR you have to change this

```
Movie2 myMovieTemp = myMovies[i];
```

into

```
Movie2 myMovieTemp = myMovies;
```

Comment: @AustinJohanningsmeier I suggest you to make habit of [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers, If the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array of Movie2 to the method `sortTitles`.
Change your sorting method `sortTitles` to have the following signature:

```
public void sortTitles(Movie2[] myMovies, int choice){
     //Rest goes here
}
```